# Interpretation of functions on spaces

Tags: functions

(i)

Can a function be seen as a set of ordered pair in the cartesian product of the domain and codomain? That is, are the function and its graph the same thing?

In practice, for D=domain, for C=codomain:

f={(x, y) $\in$ D x C |  $\forall$x: $\exists$!y}

(How does it relates to the interpretation on functions as input/output functional relations, i.e. f(x)=y?)

(ii)

In that case, is true that I can think a continuous function defined on a topological space, as a set of ordered pairs of elements of the respective topologies?

In practice, for T(D)=topology of the domain, for T(C)=topology of the codomain:

f={(x, y) $\in$ T(D) x T(C) | $\forall$x: $\exists$!y}

(so that x, y may be not only points but also sets, depending on the topologies used)

(iii)

I think that the same could be apply for measurable space.

(sorry if i'm not exactly precise in the exposition)

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: As a practical matter, sticking rigidly with this view doesn't really do you any good, but your (i) is a valid way to set up functions (minus some nonstandard notation). Your (ii) is definitely not right, though. Functions map points to points. They can be lifted to a mapping from sets to sets (the direct image mapping or the inverse image mapping), but that lift doesn't look like that.

Comment: In Set Theory a function is its graph. A set-theorist would say "If it's not the graph then which set is it?" And a binary relation, such as $<$, on a set $A$ is some (any) subset of $A\times A.$ But set-theorists still prefer to write $x<y$ for $(x,y)\in <$.

Comment: Thank you, I can see that by thinking functions as sets of pairs is correct but not exactly useful. But it seems to me a bit strange. What is the pupose of a set-theoretic definition if I can't use it in practice?

Comment: I find a post wich is talking about some of these issues. It is true that thinking functions as applied to sets or as set pairs is a bit strange, in fact some prefer type theory instead of set theory for the foundation of these objects. See there: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/01/from_set_theory_to_type_theory.html

Comment: And also this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT8NyyRgLDQ